# Для чего устанавливать поток в состояние fail()?

Tags: c++, ввод, поток-ввода

Из книги "Программирование. Принципы и практика использования с++".

```
void fillVector(istream &ist, vector<int>&v, char terminator)
{
    int i=0;
    while(ist>>i)
        v.push_back(i);
    if(ist.eof())
        return;
    if(ist.bad())
        error("поток ist поврежден");
    if(ist.fail())
    {
        ist.clear();
        char c;
        ist>>c;
        if(c!=terminator)
        {
            ist.unget();
            ist.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
}
```

В [книге](http://library.tsilikin.ru/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%A1%20%D0%B8%20%D0%A1++/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%20%D0%91%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20C++%20-%202011.pdf) на стр. 375 утверждается что нельзя получить доступ к символу без установления потока в fail(), хотя я прекрасно могу это сделать.
При установлении флага fail код не работает должным образом, то есть данная функция не возвращает символ вызывающей функции. Помогите разобраться в чем дело?

Comment: Вы явно что-то не так прочли/поняли (если это второе издание, в первом ошибок выше крыши). Приведите ссылку на текст (хотя бы просто страницу).

Comment: Добавил ссылку на контент. Просмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: В книге говорится, что если вы считываете данные - и обнаруживаете ошибку форматирования (ну, например, вы хотите считать числа из ввода типа `(5,2)`, а у вас ввод `[6]` - то следует указать это пользователю вашей функции, установив бит `fail`. Этого - **нельзя получить доступ к символу без установления потока в fail()** - я не вижу, это вы уже сами придумали, похоже. Если все считалось хорошо - все в порядке, если формат ввода неверный - вот тогда укажите, что произошла ошибка, выставив флаг `fail`.

Comment: Хорошо, но почему при установке флага в fail() функция не передает символ вызывающей функции? А если не возвращать поток в fail функция передает символ вызывающей функции.

Comment: Не понял ваш вопрос. Если все в порядке - на `fail`, грубо говоря - то все считано и получено. Если ошибка - то что передавать? И - о какой именно функции вы говорите?

Comment: достаточно лишь прочитать отрезок кода:     if(ist.fail())
    {        ist.clear();    char c;        ist>>c; ...  чтобы  рассказать что имелось ввиду.  " если введенно не число, то очистить поток, что означает установить бит good, и прочитать символ

Comment: @Harry, функция заполняет вектор числами. Например я введу не число, например, букву c и что делает в этом случае программа? Если char не равняется символу выхода из функции она должна возвращать этот же символ вызывающей функции и устанавливать поток в fail но она этого не делает. Почему?

Comment: Программа запихивает этот символ назад в поток и устанавливает для потока флаг `fail`. Т.е. вызвавший код получит поток в состоянии `fail`, а после того как снимет этот бит, первый символ, который он прочтет из потока - будет этот c.

Comment: @Harry, действительно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сначала показалось, что не имеет смысла написать ответ, но все же, думаю, будет полезно:

```
//если введено не число
if(ist.fail()) 
    {
        // установить бит `ios_base::goodbit` 
        ist.clear(); 
        char c;
        // и прочитать следующий символ
        ist>>c;
        // если этот символ не совпадает с
        //символом, переданный в аргумент функции     
        if(c!=terminator)
        {
            //приводим поток в состояние
            //когда еще не был прочтен символ
            ist.unget();
            //и очистив все биты, установим 
            //бит `ios_base::failbit`            
            ist.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
```

То же самое можно выразить и по другому:

```
if (ist.fail()) {
    ist.clear();
    if (ist.peek() != terminator)
        ist.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
}
```

А значит: если не удалось прочитать число, то приводим состояние потока в `good`, чтобы проверить является ли следующий символ `terminator` ом? Если да, то все хорошо, в обратном случаи снова устанавливаем бит `fail`. Для наглядности можем добавить проверочный код:

```
vector<int> v;
char t = ';';
fillVector(cin, v, t);  
if (cin.fail()) {
    cout << "установлен бит fail, поскольку был введен символ\n";
    cin.clear(); //очистим, чтобы прочитать этот символ
    cout  << char(cin.get()) << "а не символ " << t;
}
```

Comment: На самом деле первый и второй (использующий `ist.peek()`) фрагменты кода не эквивалентны. Второй фрагмент **всегда оставляет** вызвавший  состояние fail символ в потоке, а первый **убирает** символ, если он `terminator`. Т.о. логика вызывающей стороны должна быть разной для первого и второго случаев.

Comment: @avp, один из нас ошибается, но не вижу различия....

Comment: peek() оставляет символ в потоке. В первом варианте символ изымается из потока и опять возвращается в него, только если это не terminator. Неужели опять мои слова не понятны?